# Google PHP API autoload file - Does it replace all the individual require_once calls?

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

In much of the documentation, and many of the questions about the Google PHP API client, it shows code that looks like this:

```
<?php
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/Google_Client.php';
require_once 'google-api-php-client/src/contrib/Google_StorageService.php';
```

But is that now unneeded when using the autoloader?

```
<?php
require_once realpath(dirname(__FILE__).'/google-api-php-client/src/Google/autoload.php');
```

Comment: Yes that should replace the individual calls. As would using `vendor/autoload.php` if you installed it with composer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it replaces all the individual `require_once` calls.